# Proof dealing with Quadratic Residues

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm working on the following proof

*Let p be an odd prime number. Prove that the $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues modulo p are congruent to $$1^2,2^2,3^2,...,\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2$$*

I'm not really sure how to start this problem. What should I be looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

$$1^2,2^2,3^2,...,\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2$$

are quadratic residues because they have trivial solutions : 
$$1,2,3,\ldots, \dfrac{p-1}{2}$$

---

Next notice that $a^2\equiv (p-a)^2 \pmod{p}$ to conclude that the given list exhausts the incongruent quadratic residues modulo $p$.